# Meteor: Using raix:push and cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a mobile Meteor app for both iOS and Android. In the app I need to have push notifications and for that I'm using raix:push and it's great.
I also would like the users to sign up to the app using their Facebook account and following this great guide, I have successfully made that happen on iOS.

The problem is that the above broke my Android build. I am now getting an error when trying to run on Android:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple
>   dex files define

Researching this online, it was easy to conclude that this is because of a clash between the two plugins in the title of this issue (and in fact if I remove cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect Android runs just fine).
AFAIU, this happens because cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect uses android-support-v4.jar and not v13, but I wasn't able to understand how to fix this issue from a Meteor app.

Since signing up using Facebook and using push notifications are both very common needs, I'm hoping someone else dealt with this issue successfully on Meteor before... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work as shown in [this discussion](https://github.com/raix/push/issues/192#issuecomment-203401207).